# How to refresh project file when I switch to another branch using Android Studio terminal?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am using GIT in my Android project for version control, also I am using terminal provided in IDE to execute all the GIT related commands like add, commit , push etc. I created a new branch using `git checkout -b dev` and then modified few lines of code , after that I switched to the original master branch using `git checkout master`and I saw my original files also have been modified even though I have not merge yet.

I don't know why is this happening as it was working file earlier, could someone please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: before switch to original master branch, you should commit your changes (just commit, not push)

Comment: @PhanDinhThai before switching I didnt run any of the command like add, commit or push.

Comment: I mean you should commit your changes before switching to master branch, otherwise your changes will be keep for new check out

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: @PhanDinhThai Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `commit` changes in new branch and then move to previous branch. After `checkout -b dev` you are in new branch. Edit your files and **commit changes**. These changes will be committed to new branch and then go to you `master branch` to see same file with old snapshot.

Answer (score -1):

In android studio, there is some short cut methods to create new branches in git.In the bottom right of android studio, there is git:branch name occurs(if you installed the git). While click on that button it shows to create new branch/check out another branches/merge different branches options , please use these options for create and merge branches.